# Нужна ли запятая до слова "потому"?

Tags: пунктуация

Для последующих действий явный вид зависимости C(f) не важен (важно предположение о существовании C ), и, потому, эта зависимость не конкретизируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ни до, ни после "потому" запятая не нужна**. Трудно даже предположить мотив, на основании которого они обе могут быть поставлены. Разве что "потому" рассматривается в качестве вводного, но это полностью противоречит сложившейся практике. "Потому"  здесь союзное слово, а оно не обособляется.

***Для последующих действий явный вид зависимости C(f) не важен (важно предположение о существовании C ), и потому эта зависимость не конкретизируется.***

*Тут скорее даже у кого-то могут вопросы возникнуть по поводу первой запятой, перед И. Но это отдельный разговор.*